# What is causing format specifier error in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define MAXPOINTS 10000

// compute the average of the first num_items of buffer
double avg(double buffer[], int num_items);

//update the max and min of the first num_items of array
void maxmin(double array[], int num_items, double* max, double* min);

//shift length-1 elements of the buffer to the left and put the 
//new_item on the right.
void updatebuffer(double buffer[], int length, double new_item);



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{

    /* DO NOT CHANGE THIS PART OF THE CODE */
    double x[MAXPOINTS], y[MAXPOINTS], z[MAXPOINTS],num_z,num_y,num_x,avg_x,avg_y,avg_z,max_x,max_y,max_z,min_x,min_y,min_z;
    int lengthofavg = 0;
    if (argc>1) {
        sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &lengthofavg );
        printf("You entered a buffer length of %d\n", lengthofavg);
    }
    else {
        printf("Enter a length on the command line\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (lengthofavg <1 || lengthofavg >MAXPOINTS) {
        printf("Invalid length\n");
        return -1;
    }
    /* PUT YOUR CODE HERE */
    double max;
    double min;
    int b_up, b_down,b_left,b_right,time;
    double ax,ay,az;

    int i; 

    for(i=0;i<lengthofavg;i++)

    {
        scanf("%d, %lf, %lf, %lf, %d, %d, %d, %d", &time, &a_x, &a_y, &a_z, &Button_UP, &Button_DOWN, &Button_LEFT, &Button_RIGHT);
        x[i] = num_x; 
        y[i] = num_y; 
        z[i] = num_z; 
    }


    while(1)
    {

        scanf("%d, %lf, %lf, %lf, %d, %d, %d, %d", &time, &a_x, &a_y, &a_z, &Button_UP, &Button_DOWN, &Button_LEFT, &Button_RIGHT);
        updatebuffer(x, lengthofavg, num_x);
        updatebuffer(y, lengthofavg, num_y);
        updatebuffer(z, lengthofavg, num_z);

        avg_x= avg(x, lengthofavg);
        avg_y = avg(y, lengthofavg);
        avg_z = avg(z, lengthofavg);

        maxmin(x, lengthofavg, &max_x, &min_x);
        maxmin(y, lengthofavg, &max_y, &min_y);
        maxmin(z, lengthofavg, &max_z, &min_z);

        printf("%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf\n", num_z, num_y, num_x, avg_x, avg_y, avg_z, max_x, max_y, max_z, min_x, min_y, min_z);

        fflush(stdout);

        if(Button_LEFT == 1)

        {

            return 0;

        }
    }
}   

double avg(double buffer[], int num_items)
{
    double average = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<num_items;i++)
    {
        average = buffer[i] + average;
    }

    average = average/num_items;
    return average;
}

void maxmin(double array[], int num_items, double* max, double* min)
{
    int i = 0;
    *max = array[0];
    *min = array[0];
    for(i=0;i<num_items;i++)
    {
        if(array[i] > *max)
        {
            *max = array[i];
        }

        else if(array[i] < *min)
        {
            *min = array[i];
        }

    }
}

void updatebuffer(double buffer[], int length, double new_item)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i < length;i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = buffer[i+1];
    }
    buffer[length-1] = new_item;
}
```

Both of my '`scanf()`' statements are giving me format specifier warnings and an error for undeclared identifier.

> - warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type
>     '<dependent type>'
> - error: use of undeclared identifier

What is causing this to happen?

Comment: Concentrate on the first of [mcve].

Comment: There are no variables `Button_UP` ..., yet you are creating pointers to them.

Comment: Will adding variables (buttons, etc) set to null fix this?

Comment: maybe you can try it :P

Comment: Yes, it would fix the "error: use of undeclared identifier". You can't ever (properly) use a variable or a function until you've declared or defined it.

Comment: Note that there are `b_up`, `b_down`... already. Maybe you intended to use those?

Comment: Seems to work now, but I get this when compiling..                                              "ld: can't link with a main executable file 'lab8' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf("%d, %lf, %lf, %lf, %d, %d, %d, %d", &time, &a_x, &a_y, &a_z, &Button_UP, &Button_DOWN, &Button_LEFT, &Button_RIGHT);`

In this line all the buttons are passed without declaration.

`int b_up, b_down,b_left,b_right,time;`

Either *b_up != Button_UP* or the other way around. But not both.

try: 
`scanf("%d, %lf, %lf, %lf, %d, %d, %d, %d", &time, &a_x, &a_y, &a_z, &b_up, &b_down, &b_left, &b_right);`

Also, consider using gdb or **valgrind**, will tell you a lot more during the process of development. Not only what you have declared and not used, but also where you're being careless about heap and memory.

Happy coding!.

Comment: Neither gdb nor valgrind are of any use if the code does not compile.

Comment: Lol well, I never said it would. I just assumed he was new into it, so thought about also giving him two tools he might be not familiar with. That's why I provided what I saw wrong with the code.

Comment: @MikeGoedken Anytime!, i'm unsure on what platform you're using but also consider compiling with -Wall -Wextra flags if using gcc.

Comment: I am using gcc, what does -wall do?

Comment: @MikeGoedken I always work with -Wall -Wextra is turning up warnings by the compiler.
I know it might sound odd, but gcc is "enable" by default instead of disable by default.
It might sound weird and was discussed here https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31573 lol.

I'm trying to find an output example to leave posted on the difference.
If you find yourself having many warnings as example between #ifdef (code) #endif blocks of unused vars, you can use this macro:
#define UNUSED(expr) (void)(expr) and you just use it as a function.

Comment: Hmm.. That's interesting. Also, would you by chance know what this means? "ld: can't link with a main executable file 'lab8' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" I get this after compiling..

Comment: @MikeGoedken here you have an example:
Same project compiled with -Wall -Wextra and without:
[link](http://owncloud.derekdemuro.com/index.php/s/2Upf09GlXryVlXd/download)

Comment: @MikeGoedken that sounds like a linker error. What files do you have in your program? just lab8.cpp or something else? How are you calling the compiler?

Comment: what's the output of:
" gcc -o lab8 lab8.c -Wall -Wextra" ?

Comment: You were right it was a linker error, I fixed it. Thanks for help!

Comment: @MikeGoedken glad you were able to fix it! :) hope to see you around!.

Answer (score 0):

The variables you declared do not match the variables you passed to the scanf functions:

```
 int b_up, b_down,b_left,b_right,time;
 double ax,ay,az;

 scanf("%d, %lf, %lf, %lf, %d, %d, %d, %d", &time, &a_x, &a_y, &a_z, &Button_UP, &Button_DOWN, &Button_LEFT, &Button_RIGHT);
```

change them like this:

```
 scanf("%d, %lf, %lf, %lf, %d, %d, %d, %d", &time, &ax, &ay, &az, &b_up, &b_down, &b_left, &b_right);
```